# Error message trying to get expo device token for push notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to get push notifications on iOS working. Here is how I am doing it:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import Notifications from 'expo';

async componentDidMount() {

    await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
    .then((response) =>
        response.status === 'granted'
            ? response
            : Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
    )
    .then(async(response) => {
        if (response.status !== 'granted') {

            this.setState({
                pushStatus: false
            })


            return Promise.reject(new Error('Push notifications permission was rejected'));
        }

        
        const token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
        console.log(token);
        return token;
    })
    .then(token => {
        Firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({
            token: token,
            pushStatus: this.state.pushStatus
        }, { merge: true })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error while registering device push token', error);
    });
}
```

But im getting the following error when running on iOS:

```
Error while registering device push token [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.default.getExpoPushTokenAsync')]
```

I am running it by scanning the QR code on my iPhone which opens up the expo app and runs the application. When I accept the permission for push notifications, I get the error.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Updating expo SDK from 39 to 40 and importing notifications like this did the trick:

```
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According with the documentation you should use `expo-notifications` instead of just `expo` while importing `Notifications`.
Also, the import statement should be as follows:

```js
import * as Notification from “expo-notifications”
```

Think that when you import from expo as you are, you are importing all the expo functions/utilities/etc under the name of Notification.

I think that that’s the reason why it throws undefined on the object. Anything else I could do to help let me know.

——

EDIT:

After an exhaustive search, the problem was the incompatibility between the SDK and the notification library.

For `expo-notifications` 0.82 SDK 40 is needed, otherwise it will not work throwing the errors listed in the question and the comments of this answer.

Comment: I am aware of this, and am using what I am using because when I `import * as Notification from “expo-notifications”` I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ServerRegistrationModule.default.getRegistrationInfoAsync')`. Lots of answers on stack overflow either recommend one or the other, but the way I am doing it is the only way that works for me without throwing that error

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: typing expo-cli --version in terminal tells me 4.0.17

Comment: actually im on 39, should I upgrade to 40?

Comment: The expo SDK is located on your package.json under the expo key. Also, are you logged in on the expo-cli? If you are not, try logging you in before testing push notifications. Sometimes that’s the real issue

Comment: Yep, logged in, package.json says "expo": "^39.0.5",

Comment: I tested push notifications on SDK 39 and 40 and they work for me. So I don’t think that changing the SDK will do the trick

Comment: Ill try anyway, just read the docs for 40 and none of the breaking changes should affect my project

Comment: updating the SDK didn't fix things, but I did solve another problem which is good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227242/discussion-between-luckongas-and-kalculated).

Comment: @luckongas I am facing this same error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ServerRegistrationModule.default.getRegistrationInfoAsync')` what was the solution you found to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: During the chat with the OP updating de expo SDK version solved the problem. After some research we found out that this was a bug with the library https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11295

Comment: Installing using the expo cli fixed it for me, like so `expo add expo-notifications` instead of `yarn add expo-notifications`. Using the expo cli makes sure the correct dependency is downloaded.